# Is this C++ code correct?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class My
{
public:
    My(int &val) : m_val(val)
    {
        std::cout << "int& constructor" << std::endl;
        Print();
    }
    My(const My& my) : m_val(my.m_val)
    {
        std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
        Print();
    }
    My &operator=(const My&)
    {
        std::cout << "operator =" << std::endl;
        Print();
        return *this;
    }
    
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "m_val ptr = " << &m_val << std::endl;
        std::cout << "m_val     = " << m_val  << std::endl;
    }
    
    int &m_val;
};

int main() {
    My my = my;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this C++ code correct? I was surprised when this code has compiled on gcc and msvc.

Output of this program is:

> copy constructor
>
> m_val ptr = 0xb74a36e5
>
> m_val     = 1528349827

upd: I concerned about the line

```
My my = my;
```

Comment: Why do you ask? Does something about it make you think it *isn't*?

Comment: what do you mean, "correct"? code which compiles and runs doesn't mean it's "correct"... `system('rm -rf /')` would compile/execute "correctLy", but not many people would actually consider that a "correct" program.

Comment: I guess you need a pre-tutor

Comment: Presumably the OP is concerned about the `My my = my;` line.

Comment: It isn't "correct". For one, you have a dangling reference.

Comment: `I was surprised when this code has compiled on gcc and msvc.` C++ does not like to hold your hand. You can shoot yourself in the foot at every step (until you've shot both feet, then you fall over). /analogy

Comment: @codah - unless you are walking on your hands

Comment: @EdHeal but then you can't hold the gun. Anyway the analogy ended :)

Comment: @codah, Hold the gun with your feet. If people can do [this](http://youtu.be/ihnnRZhculg), I imagine they can also do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's correct in the sense of being well-formed, so it compiles. The scope of a name begins as soon as it's declared, so a variable name can be used in its own initialiser.

It's incorrect in the sense of having undefined behaviour, using the uninitialised value of an object.